# redirect to new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prettyphoto

I use a login script (nothing fancy really) which leads to a small member area - I was wondering if it's possible to change this so that once that the user credentials are being submitted the restricted are will open in a new window?

Here a sample of my code:

```
    <?php
      define("_VALID_PHP", true);
      require_once("init.php");
      if ($user->logged_in)
          redirect_to("welcome.php");
      if (isset($_POST['doLogin']))
          : $result = $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
      if ($result)
          : redirect_to("welcome.php");
      endif;
      endif;
    ?>
```

And here the form:

```
     <form action="" method="post" id="login_form" name="login_form">
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <div style="text-align:center; color:#F00; margin-bottom:20px;" id="msgholder-alt"><?php print $core->showMsg;?></div>  
        <p> 
            <label for="username" class="uname" > Your Username:</label>
            <input id="username" name="username" required type="text" />
        </p>
        <p> 
            <label for="password" class="youpasswd"> Your Password: </label>
            <input id="password" name="password" required type="password" /> 
        </p>
        <p class="login button"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submitlogin" /> 
            <input name="doLogin" type="hidden" value="1" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated - thank you.

Comment: You could get some JavaScript to open a new page (prepare for pop-up blockers). But then, what about the login page? Best way, is what you have right now.

Comment: Thank you for your message Dave Chen - the thing is I have the index page (which contains the login form) loaded in a prettyphoto iframe. Once I submit the details the restricted area (welcome.php) is visible in this iframe. I would like to change this around so that once the username and password have been submitted the welcome.php page opens in a new window. Is there a way to have this accomplished?

Comment: Why not affect the parent frame instead? `window.top.location.href = 'welcome.php';`

Comment: Where would I need to add this code?

Comment: Replace `redirect_to("welcome.php");` with it, and remember to place an `exit` at the end.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Chen for the kind advise - I have tried your method but I am getting a syntax error: <?php
  define("_VALID_PHP", true);
  require_once("init.php");
  if ($user->logged_in)
      redirect_to("welcome.php");
  if (isset($_POST['doLogin']))
      : $result = $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
  if ($result)
      : window.top.location.href = 'welcome.php'; exit
  endif;
  endif;
?>

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, this is JavaScript. `echo '<script>window.top.location.href = "welcome.php";</script>'; exit;`

Comment: OUTSTANDING, I had to replace the 'welcome.php' with "welcome.php" as I've gotten a syntax error but now it works absolutely fine! THANK YOU so much Mr. Chen - this made my day